# graphviz Python Node Shapes-Pie Chart in a node

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphviz, pygraphviz, pygraph

I am writing a Python script to generate a network graph using graphviz. Some of my nodes represents injection into a network and I am wondering if it is possible to have a Pie-Chart inside some of the nodes.

Python code for a simple two node network is following:

```
import graphviz as gv

g1 = gv.Graph(format='svg')
g1.node('A')
g1.node('B')
g1.edge('A', 'B')

filename = g1.render(filename='img/g1')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I let the PyGraphViz implementation up to you. But to answer to the core of your question, since graphviz 2.30, you can use the `wedged` style for nodes, to achieve the desired result. Here is an example in plain dot:

```
digraph G {
  {
    node [shape=circle style=wedged fillcolor="red;0.3:green;0.6:orange"]
    A
    node [style=solid fillcolor="white" ]
    B
    C
  }

B -> A
B -> C
}
```

[image: Dot pie chart nodes]

The list of colors is expressed as a **colon** separated list. The value after the **semi-colon* in the weight of the given color. The sum of all weights must be equal to 1.0. See the [colorList attribute](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#kcolorList)

Comment: Or donuts: see my code pen, "[Donut charts in d3-graphviz](https://codepen.io/GrahamHannington/pen/agZjeV)".